# updating an app in code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I wish to update the app in future, so what are code to be added in my present app, so that it detects the changes in the updates and implement the changes automatically. 
Notes related to the topic is more helpful...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updation of your `iOS` App Once you submit a new version and is approved by `Apple`, your previous binary will no longer be available to the consumer, your latest binary will be the only version of the application available in the `AppStore`.

This means that new users will only download the latest version and existing users will got the notification for new updated version and they can skip versions when updating. Versions must be standalone and not "`patches`" for previous versions.

In Appliation there is no need to add any kind of code that tell user for updation.

Comment: if the existing user wants to clicks on the update does it reinstall the application ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't update an app in code

Comment: actually i have seen this code.                                     NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *build = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
so i was confused wheather i can use this in code?

Comment: so how does the update of an app process take place ... i have seen some reports stating that they have an app crash when updated the app?

Comment: Read the Tools Workflow for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH1-SW1